# How can I automatically increment Strings/ints for efficency?

Tags: java, arraylist

Say this is my code:

```
String name = in1.next();
int highNumber = in1.nextInt();
int lowNumber = in1.nextInt();

System.out.println(name +" " + highNumber +" " + lowNumber);
```

Is there a way that I can add a number infront of `name` if it's not 12?
Or is there a way to create an `ArrayList` to do the same thing?

I need to get 12 lines from a file each with a `name`, `highNumber`, and `lowNumber`
I want to be able to manipulate each like separately for an equation and also altogether.

File:

```
Edward 33 22
Billy  22 14
Fred   44 43
Jim    12  1
Andy   3   2
...
```

Expected Output:

```
Name             High             Low             Average            Range
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Billy             22                14             18                  8
...

Total Averages
Total Highs
Total Lows
```

Alternative of doing something like this:

```
String name2 = in1.next();
int highNumber2 = in1.nextInt();
int lowNumber2 = in1.nextInt();
String name3 = in1.next();
int highNumber3 = in1.nextInt();
int lowNumber3 = in1.nextInt();
String name4 = in1.next();
int highNumber4 = in1.nextInt();
int lowNumber4 = in1.nextInt();
...
String name12 = in1.next();
int highNumber12 = in1.nextInt();
int lowNumber12 = in1.nextInt();
```

I am restricted into using `Scanner` and `PrintWriter`. :(

Comment: my apologies, meant `name`, editted

Comment: Where is month in your code? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: what type is name and what manipulations with what kind of output do you have in mind?

Comment: Provided some additions to the post with what I am working with. Hopefully it makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

you could store the data of every line in an object like this

```
public class Record {
    private String name;
    private Integer high;
    private Integer low;

    public Record(String name, Integer high, Integer, low) {
        this.name = name;
        this.high = high;
        this.low = low;
    }

    public Record(String line) {
        String[] parts = line.split(" ");
        name = parts[0].trim();
        high = new Integer(parts[1].trim());
        low = new Integer(parts[2].trim());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Integer getHigh() {
        return high;
    }

    public Integer getLow() {
        return low;
    }

    public Integer getAvg() {
        return (high + low) / 2;
    }

    public Integer getRange() {
        return (high - low);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + '\t' + high + '\t' + low  +'\t' + getAvg() + '\t' + getRange();
    }
}
```

Then stuff the lines read from your file into new Record objects, append them to a list and finally iterate over the list to print your table

```
List<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();
String name;
Integer high;
Integer low;

for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    name = in1.next();
    high = in1.nextInt();
    low = in1.nextInt();

    records.add(new Record(name, high, low));
}

for(Record record : records) {
    System.out.println(record);
}
```

Comment: I will try this, I like the usage of more than one method and how each part is seen. Will it work for all 12 lines?

Comment: i cant seem to get the stored data and append them to a list

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(new File(""));
System.out.println("Id\tName\tHigh\tLow\tAvg\tRange");
int id=1;
while(input.hasNext())
{
String name=input.next();
int high=input.nextInt();
int low=input.nextInt();
System.out.println(id+"\t"+name+"\t"+high+"\t"+low+"\t"+((high+low)/2)+"\t"+(high-low));
id++;
}
```

Are you expecting this??? Give more details..

Comment: I will try this, from the looks of it, it sort of makes sense. Don't understand the `while` though.

Comment: 'while loop' is used to read each line until the last line of file.

Comment: oooo, That's interesting. I'll try it out and see what I can do with it. x)

Answer (score 0):

probably a read line?

```
BufferedReader File = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileOpen));   
     String str;
     str = File.readLine( );
```

when first line read then do again readLine() with a boucle for(){}

Comment: I'm actually restricted in using `FileReader1, I have to use `Scanner` and `PrintWriter`. I will mention that in my post, I apologize!